# Exclamation mark as part of an indexer?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I just saw odd syntax after decompiling a dictionary in .net core 3.1 and I cant find any information about it

**What does the `!` mean in this context ? `if (i >= 0) return _entries![i].value;`**

Here is the full code for the indexer for more context

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) return _entries![i].value;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException(key);
        return default;
    }
    set
    {
        bool modified = TryInsert(key, value, InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting);
        Debug.Assert(modified);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any information / link about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does exclamation mark mean before invoking a method in C# 8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230542/what-does-exclamation-mark-mean-before-invoking-a-method-in-c-sharp-8-0)

Comment: I did do a search but did not find that question, thanks! (Will close my question shortly to avoid duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

This is [`null-forgiving operator !`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) which helps to explicitly tell the compiler that `__entries` can't be a nullable reference.

It was added in scope of introducing a [nullable references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) in C# 8.0. When nullable context is enabled, all reference types are recognized as non-nullable ones. Compiler generates a warning when reference can be a `null` possibly. `!` operator allows you to tell the compiler that particular reference can't be a `null` at the given context